# mysqli_connect() No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in C:\xampp\htdocs\GPS_Distance\OTPverify.php on line 29

Tags: php

My code is correct I`ll check it 5 to 6 times and my first page is running properly but in second page it is producing error and port address and everything is right....

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

if you are running sql server on other machine you have to provide **ip-address** f that machine instead of **localhost.** and make sure Mysql service is started

also one thing in if condition change it to `>`  because if it has more than one record else will execute .